# Calling a Javascript only with the button class

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am new to Javascript and also new to this Website.

I have about 40 Buttons which are all in the class "foo".
I also have a Javascript function named "run".
How can I set the Javascript to run whenever one of the buttons in class "foo" is pressed without actually setting the button to run it?

Is this even Possible?

Comment: Consider jQuery to easily select all button by class and assigning one click function to all of them at once. Please update your question if pure JavaScript solution is required

Comment: you will save a lot of time using jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Here is an example using jQuery.

```
$('.foo').click(function() {

    run();

});
```

OR, using plain old JavaScript (see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2TL2K/3/)):

```
          //generates a "NodeList" of all buttons
var foo = document.getElementsByTagName('button'),
          //then, we turn it into an actual array
    foo = Array.prototype.slice.call(foo);

foo.forEach(function(button) {

    //check to see if that button has the class "foo"
    if(button.classList.contains('foo')) {
        button.onclick = function() {
             return run();   
        };
    }

});

function run() {
    console.log('run');   
}
```

You could use

> getElementsByClassName

but the downside of that, is that the only version of IE in which it is supported is 9+ (including all other major browsers), which is fine, if that's what you decide to go with.

Comment: Your first example could just be `$('.foo').click(run)` although this is probably better for learning

Comment: Correct! Thank you for clarifying that for the OP.  Both ways are possible.

Comment: getElementsByClassName is supported in Firefox and Chrome. http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname

Answer (score 1):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d577L/)

You can copy + paste this right into your code and should work perfectly.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    addEvent(buttons[i], 'click', run);
}

function addEvent(element, myEvent, fnc) {
    return ((element.attachEvent) ? element.attachEvent('on' + myEvent, fnc) : element.addEventListener(myEvent, fnc, false));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery:

```
var foos = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

for (var i=0; i<foos.length; i++) {
    foos[i].onclick = function() { run() };
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8AKeP/

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 simple ways to accomplish this.

First, you can just use plain vanilla Javascript. No external libraries are required.

```
// Get all buttons
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

// Loop through the buttons
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    // Tell each button that when it is clicked, call the "run" function.
    buttons[i].onclick = run;
}
```

Second, You can specify the onclick methods in your HTML.  This is a bad approach as it forces you to define global methods (functions that are accessible from anywhere), and also ties your code with your markup, making it hard to change one without changing the other.

```
<!-- Old HTML -->
<button class="foo">Text</button>

<!-- New HTML -->
<button class="foo" onclick="run()">Text</button>
```

Lastly, You can include the **very** helpful [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library to handle it for you.  jQuery provides an easy way to handle binding events, selecting elements, etc.:

```
// One line (deconstruction below)
//  $(".foo")    => Find me all elements with a class name of "foo"
//  .on("click", => When those elements are clicked
//  run);        => Call the "run" method.
$(".foo").on("click", run);
```

The last approach, using jQuery has become the sort of de facto standard way of doing this.

Comment: It should be noted for beginners' sake that calling code from attributes is very much frowned upon as it mixes your code with markup and forces you to expose global methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery, for example:

```
$('.foo').click(function(){
        run();
});
```

it is simpler to program. However, without using jQuery:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');


function run(){
    alert('hi');
}

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    buttons[i].onclick = function() { run() };
}
```

Comment: foo is a class not an element. Please fix your jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var run = function(){
 //your function goes here
}

$(document).on('click', '.foo', run);
```